# Passing PHP data value to javascript securely

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to pass a user-id from php to javascript, however the challenge is adding an "are you sure you want to proceed" pop-up option. My goal is to pass the ID via the HTML tag using data-value, however I run into the error where the user could just change the value using Google Dev tools. Is there a way around this?

Here's the HTML
*The code is displayed with PHP, so $user_id (and the others) are all PHP variables that are added to each instance of the user-box

```
<div class='user-line'>
    <div class='user-upper-line'>
        <div class='user-id'><b>ID: </b>$user_id</div>
        <div class='user-name'>$user_fName $user_lName</div>
    </div>
    <a href='mailto:$user_email' title='Email $user_fName' class='user-email-link'><div class='user- 
    email'><b>Email: </b>$user_email</div></a>
    <div class='user-role'><b>User Role:<br id='role-br'> </b>$user_role</div>
    <div class='user-view-profile'><a href='#' class='noSelect user-view-profile-btn' title=\"View $user_fName's Profile\">View Profile</a>
    <div class='noSelect user-update-permissions' title=\"Update $user_fName's Permissions\">Update Permissions</div>
    <div class='noSelect user-delete-profile-btn' data-value='$user_id' title=\"Delete $user_fName's Account\">Delete User</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
    $(".user-delete-profile-btn").click(function() {

        id = $(this).attr("data-value");

        alert(id);

        $(".delete-account-overlay").stop(true).fadeIn(500);

    });
```

Comment: >user could just change the value using Google Dev tools. Is there a way around this?  In short, no.  Javascript is executed by the browser, so, you will never be able to prevent the user for messing with it.  This is why you always validate on the backend.

Comment: I'm struggling to figure out how to validate on the backend, because though I can get the ID to the javascript click function - I'm not sure how to verify that against the equivalent PHP ID

Comment: So what is the problem really? If I change the user id in console and then submit... what is the problem with that? Can you explain what exactly needs to be protected or why that is undesirable? Would I do something that really should not be allowed? Why?

Comment: You haven't given us any context or requirements. Is the user limited to deleting themselves? Are they logged in? Do they have a role?

Comment: You need something of the user stored at the server (ex. session), which you can use to compare to the passed ID. You can't just validate a plain ID to belong to the user who passed it to the server. Think about an ID on the client: `123456`, then the client changes it to `124321`, there's no way you could validate the ID not belonging to the client passed it to you, if you can't compare it to something, and the server will fluently delete someone else's account.

Comment: I think there's a fundamental misunderstanding here, _Passing PHP data value to javascript securely_. PHP and JS don't talk to each other. There is simply a flow of requests/responses to/from the client/server. When the request comes in to the server, you need to validate that the current user (session) is allowed to delete the person who is described by the request. If you don't have the current user (session) then you won't be able to do any validation.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand you correctly you want to be able to have the user id accessible in the client and be certain that the id can't be changed?

Generally, everything served to the frontend/client should most of the time be considered as data which cannot be guaranteed to not be manipulated, however there are some ways around this if you're cool with the user being able to see the value (but not change it). What you could use is, for example, JSON web tokens (https://jwt.io/) which are a very neat concept I myself use all the time.

You basically sign the data, thereby you can instantly see if anything has been changed. This is a secure way of storing information in the client and still being sure that it can't be changed

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you do a good validation on the backend, however, you can use this `document.oncontextmenu = function () {return false}` 
avoiding the use of devtools, although you really shouldn’t just rely on tricks, it’s best to validate the backend correctly using Json Web Tokens (jwt)